# "You do not have authorization to perform that action."

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that contains this simple script:

```
function onOpen() {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "Create Mailing List", functionName: "createMail"}];  
  ss.addMenu("ROMEO", menuEntries);
}

function createMail(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
  var rng = ss.getRange(2, 3, 100).getValues();
  var arr = new Array();
  for(var i=0; i<rng.length; i++) {
    var email = rng[i][0];      
    if (email.length == 0) break;      
    arr[i] = email;
  }
  ss.getRange(2,5).setValue(arr.join(",")).activate();
}
```

I've shared the spreadsheet with 3 users who all have "Can Edit" permission. Two users can perform the createMail function by clicking the added menu item. The third user can see the added menu item, but when he clicks it he receives "You do not have authorization to perform that action."

Some details about this third user:

1. He logs in using a yahoo.com email address. Everyone else uses a gmail.com address.
2. He uses IE on Windows 8. The others are on Win 7 or lower.

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The yahoo user doesnt actually have a google account but you need one to execute apps script functions.
by sharing a doc with him google is just sharing it "by url" and not really with him until he creates a google account.

Comment: To test this see if you can open the spreadsheet from an incognito window (with no account signed in) using the url he has.

Answer (score 0):

Three possible solutions:

1. The third user needs to be signed into a Google account when accessing the Spreadsheet.
2. Make your Spreadsheet **public** (to the entire world - will be indexed by search engines).
3. Make your Spreadsheet *editable* to *anyone who has a direct link* (this is an option in the Share menu).